# Unpacking sequences in python

Tags: python, sequence, iterable-unpacking

I started learning python few weeks ago(with no previous knowledge in programming), and went onto the following problem related to unpacking of sequences, which confuses me a lot.

For some reason when I try this:

```
for b, c in [1,2]:
    print b,c
```

I am getting an error message:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

The same happens when I try to replace the list with a tuple (1,2)

But when I try the same thing, just with a tuple inside of list:

```
for b, c in [(1,2)]:
    print b,c
```

it works - I get:

> 1 2

Why is that?

Thank you.

btw I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everytime you do a `in <iterable>` statement, it fetches one item from the iterable and then unpacks it according to your needs, in your case `b, c`. So, in the first example, you try to assign `b, c` to `1` which is not possible, whereas in next example you do `b, c = (1, 2)` which unpacks successfully and gives you a b, c.

For example, try to print out the values.

```
>>> for x in [1, 2]:
        print "X: ", x


X:  1
X:  2

>>> for x in [(1, 2)]:
        print "X: ", x


X:  (1, 2)
```

So, assigning `b, c = 1` is not possible, whereas assigning `b, c = (1, 2)` is possible.

Comment: `b=c=1` is probably what a person would *intend* with the invalid `b,c=1` example.

Answer (score 6):

In Python, a `for` loop takes each item from the iterable, and assigns it to the given name(s), before executing the code block each time.

In the first case, Python takes the first item, `1` and tries to assign it to `b, c` - this doesn't work as there is only one value to assign, hence the error.

In the second example, the first value is the entire tuple `(1, 2)` - so this *can* be unpacked, as it contains the two required values.

It's clear what the issue is when you put it into context:

```
a, b = 1, 2
a, b = 1
```

One value can't become two.